# How to call a batch file from a Visual Studio Code extension command into the Integrated Terminal

Tags: node.js, batch-file, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am posting this question becouse I am having a great deal of trouble to obtain the desired behaviour: call an external batch file (.bat) and execute it in the integrated terminal in VSCode.

It should be noted that this batch file in question calls a compiler which may take a few seconds to compile.

My first aproach was to follow the vscode documentation and write a task to run my batch script file in the terminal. However, while the batch file was indeed called by the task it would randomly crash with the following error:

```
C:\UThe terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

By randomly I mean that sometimes it would crash and sometimes it would not (for the same exact script). I also started noticing that the longer the compiler called by the batch file took to compile, the more likely was the crash, which leads me to suspected that the vscode integrated terminal does not like unresponsive processes being called, so it crashes itself? I do not know.

It is also worth nothing that if I call this batch file from the command line or powershell it will run 100% of the time, it only crashes when called via vscode task.

This leads us to my second aproach to execute this batch file from visual studio code. I created an extension that implements a custom vscode command that calls the batch file via NODE.js.

```
disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.forceBuild', function (file) {
    console.log(rootPath);
    compiler.processControl(compiler.control_file,compiler.project_path);
    let execute_command = "start " + rootPath + "\\build.bat"  
    child_process.exec(execute_command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        if(error) console.log(error);
        if(stderr) console.log(stderr);
    });
});
```

This also works, however it will launch a new terminal window instead of using the integrated terminal of visual studio code. My question is if there is anyway to use or hook this batch file to the integrated terminal window.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for your original question?

Answer (score 0):

Just cut out the "start" command

```
let execute_command = rootPath + "\\build.bat"
```